# How do you set up a TFS build definition with default parameters?

Tags: tfsbuild

I'd like to set up a build definition in TFS that calls a particular build target and passes in default parameters. Is there a way to do this without setting up a new tfsbuild.proj file for my new definition?

All the functionality I want to use already exists in our main build script, I just want an easy way for people to be able to call it without having to know the exact parameters to pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything that can be configured for a TFS 2008 build the following article may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458792.aspx

I think the only way to supply default parameters without editing the TFSbuild.proj file itself is to supply a response file. So if your TFS build definition is in TFSBuild.proj you add a TFSBuild.rsp file which I guess will need to be different for each environment. In TFS 2010 it looks like you can setup defaults but I'm not working with 2010 at the moment so can't comment accurately.

This link is looks useful if you're on 2010:
http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx